# jQuery mobile tap event fires vclick

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a jQuery mobile application that should work on mobile devices and on PC. I'm using the jQuery Finger plugin (http://ngryman.sh/jquery.finger/) to detect finger events:

```
$('body').on('tap', 'image', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

The problem is that the the tap event is triggered twice.

```
[1] v.Event {type: "tap", x: 600, y: 374, orientation: null, end: false…}

[2] v.Event {originalEvent: v.Event, type: "tap", timeStamp: 1440756290573, jQuery183031088717421516776: true, toElement: image#7…}
```

When I collapse the 2nd event information in developer tools, the type shows "vclick".

```
...
shiftKey: false
srcElement: image#7
target: image#7
timeStamp: 1440756501237
toElement: image#7
type: "vclick"
view: Window
which: 1
__proto__: Object
...
```

How can I prevent this from happening so the event only runs the jQuery finger tap event and not the vclick?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` or simple ignore of `vclick` Event?

Comment: I have tried them both. I cannot ignore it because I use it to call a function that only should run once.

Comment: You can ignore first call or second one. Or you can gather some information on first call, gather some information on second call and call whatever function you need after this.

Comment: These `Event` objects have enough distinctions to understand which one is what and to make desicion. Or you can rewrite plugin - it might help. Nevertheless, if noone will offer better solution, try to differentiate events.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the 'ignore it' comment. If I ignore it the function/code inside the tap event is fired twice resulting in unsolvable problems.

Comment: I do not need the event information, I just need to run code when the event is fired. The code should only run once and not twice.

Comment: I see only three ways: 1. Looking in event information to understand what the event is. 2. Somehow block firing of second event. 3. Usage of random number to determine whether to handle event or not: who knows - maybe you are the lucky one. About first way (even though you somewhy don't want to look at event): [here is examle](http://jsfiddle.net/37hksgc4/) of how to sort events based on `originalEvent`. It should be `event.originalEvent`, but for test case it is used as separate parameter.

Comment: Thanks Regent, I did not know how to sort events like that. Problem solved (you will get upvote if you post it as an answer).

Comment: You're welcome. I can try to form my example as answer, if you are ready to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate events (to ignore them or to do special handling) by checking events' specific fields.

In this particular case, I see the difference in `originalEvent` field. So to handle only second event you can use something like this (`event.originalEvent` is replaced with function's argument `originalEvent` for test purposes):

```js
$(document).on('tap', function(event, originalEvent) {
    if (originalEvent) {
        console.log('Time to handle event');
        //code code code
    }
    else {
        console.log('Ignoring event');
    }
});

$(document).trigger('tap');
$(document).trigger('tap', ['v.Event']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```